# Instancing Java Class that could be a concrete or interface class

Tags: java, class, hadoop, interface, factory

I am working to port a large codebase from one version of an API to another (Specifcally Hadoop CDH3 to Hadoop CDH4).

During the "upgrade" of these libraries, someone decided to change a commonly used concrete class (JobContext) into an interface and move all it's functionality into a sub class (JobContextImpl). Normally this would be a fairly straight forward proposition. However, we are still required to maintain support for the old version of the libraries, thus supporting the class as both a concrete and interface.

We could obviously have 2 different sets of jars that we could swap out depending on the version of hadoop we're using but that will cause a lot of unnecessary head ache for us down the road. I would like to create one version that would run against both hadoop versions.

Naturally the factory pattern would be the first thing to pop into your mind but the problem with that is the implementation class in the new version doesn't exist in the previous version, therefore the code will only compile against one set of the libraries at one time and only run against one.

Next I've attempted to use a groovyscript and some clever reflection to detect which version of the library is in the classpath. I'm able to instance the objects but using one the library I didn't compile against gives me the:

IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.pain.MyContext, but class was expected

EDIT:
In summary I need to be able to instance a class that can be either a concrete class or interface. I can detect which it is and I know where the implementation is if it is an interface, but if concrete then that implementation class doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the JVM to ignore a binary incompatibility; i.e. contradictory definitions of the same type.

It *might* be possible to work around the problem, but it would be extremely awkward.

What you would need to do is:

- eliminate ALL direct and indirect references to the `JobContext` class from your source code,
- replace ALL variables of type `JobContext` with `Object`
- replace ALL calls to methods and constructors that take `JobContext` as a parameter or return it as a result with reflective method or constructor calls, using a `Class<?>` for `JobContext` that you obtained using `Class.forName(...)`.

In short, if you can get rid of all places where your code uses or depends on a statically loaded `JobContext`, then you won't get any `IncompatibleClassChangeError` exceptions for that class.

---

To be honest, I think you are better off just compiling your codebase separately against the two Hadoop APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm tending to agree. Even if I could instance them I have yet to find a way to cast it to the appropriate type at runtime to pass it back to hadoop. You have to be explicit when passing to other libraries...